# How to create sub-directories from an array of strings?

Tags: bash

I create an array of random strings with size *n.* given a certain input (levels or depth).

I would like to create a structure of sub-directories, e.g. `arr=(a 32ae frew qw3 gt2 ffrghaw dwe)` and at level 4 I want to create `a/32ae/frew/qw3`.

I am trying to access the array but I cant get the right result.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$2" -lt 0 ];
then
    echo "<Num of files must be zero or positive number!>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$3" -lt 0 ];
then
    echo "<Num of directories must be zero or positive number!>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$4" -lt 0 ];
then
    echo "<Levels must be zero or positive number!>"
    exit 1
fi

dir=$1

if [ ! -d "$dir" ];
then
    mkdir -p "$dir"
else
    echo "<Directory $dir exists!>"
fi

num_of_files=$2
num_of_dirs=$3
leves=$4
arr=()

for(( i=0; i<"$num_of_dirs"; i++ ))
do 
    random_num=$(( 1 + RANDOM % 8 ))
    string=$(cat /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w "$random_num" | head -n 1)
    arr=("${arr[@]}" "$string")
    mkdir -p $dir/"$string" && touch $dir/"$string"/aek.txt

    #echo "$string"
done


echo ${arr[0]}...${arr[3]}
echo
```

I get something like `a/{232[1]}` or `a/{ae[1],ae[2],ae[3]}`

Comment: This is pretty gappy. Did you forget `dir=$1` or am I guessing wrong? Can you explain in more detail the logic of the `for` loop and the actual end goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what these parameters are supposed to represent, but how's this as a simplification?

```
tree=$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' </dev/urandom |
    fold -w 8 |
    head -n 4 |
    tr '\n' /)
mkdir -p "$tree" && touch "$tree"aek.txt
```

As an added bonus, this doesn't require any Bash-only functionality.

This will most likely create directory names which are all 8 characters long. If that's a problem, perhaps add a snippet to shorten some of them with some probability. Perhaps randomly select some alphabetics to remove from the generated string with `tr -d`?