# Determine the maximum path length of a directory in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create an hierarchy of directories and files. The idea is the following : i want my script to create my directories level by level

So lets say the user types these commands from command line

```
/dirname  #dirs=8 #levels=2
```

and i want it to create something like this:

```
/dirname

|-->/a/b
|
|-->/b/c
|
|-->/e/f
|
|-->/g/h
```

How can i determine the number of paths i will have in my directories

i've tried with PATH_MAX  but it doesnt seem to work

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG_NUM=$#    #argc
echo $#

if [ $ARG_NUM -ne 3 ];then
    echo "Wrong number of aguments"
  exit 1
fi

# ROOT_DIR
dir_name=$1
if [[ ! -d $dir_name ]]; then
    mkdir $dir_name

fi

#CREATING FOLDERS WITH RANDOM NAMES
LIMIT=$3
for ((j=1; j<=LIMIT; j++))
do
     mkdir -p $dir_name/$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
     echo $dir_name "created"
done
```

Comment: This looks awfully similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337058/how-to-create-sub-directories-from-an-array-of-strings (and roughly equally unclear).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "How can I determine the number of paths I will have in my directories?" Also, you never use `$2`

Comment: what i'm trying my bash do is to start by creating directories level-by-level until it creates #num_of_dirs directories  #level levels. For instance we have these directory names, aaa, bbb, cc, dddd, eee  , num_of_dirs=5 and levels=2 i want my bash to create this:                                                                                  dir_name/aaa/ ,
dir_name/aaa/bbb , 
dir_name/cc/ , 
 dir_name/cc/dddd , 
 dir_name/eee